# Mapview (litemode) in listview showing only one map

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-mapview

Using this code, only the map for the second item shows. 
All the maps have the google logo (bottom left) and the button to open the map in GoogleMaps (bottom right), but the rest is blank.
After scrolling down and back up, that one disappears too.

Right now all the maps are loading the same address, but that will change obviously.

My other option is to use static maps, but would like to find out if litemode mapview can work or not.

**CustomGrid.java**

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    Bundle savedInstanceState;

    private GoogleMap map;

    private final String[] eventname;

    String finaldate;

    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);



    //private final int[] Imageid;

    //public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
    public CustomGrid(Context c, final Bundle b, String[] eventname, String[] date, String[] venue, String[] city, String[] state, String[] catA, String[] catB, String[] pricerange, Double[] price) {
        mContext = c;
        //this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.eventname = eventname;
        this.savedInstanceState = b;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return eventname.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            //grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            //grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);

        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        /*
        TextView textView_eventname = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text_eventname);
        TextView textView_location = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text_location);
        TextView textView_pricerange = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text_pricerange);
        */

        TextView textView_eventname = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.event_name);

        textView_eventname.setText(eventname[position]);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) grid.findViewById(R.id.event_map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        map = mapView.getMap();

        MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);


        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Me")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)));

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        return grid;
    }


}
```

The function that calls custom grid to create the tiles

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.event_grid);

        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(EventGrid.this, savedInstanceState, eventname);
        grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);    
    }
```

**grid_single.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3E3E3E"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/event_map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#3E3E3E"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        map:cameraZoom="13"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:liteMode="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about a situation like this. Did you add your API Key properly?   [Signup and API Keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

The direction and the Map logos will appear when you click on the marker only

Add you Debug/Release 
[Android SHA1 certificate fingerprint](http://androidcodegeeks.com/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint/) on [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com)

**EDIT: Working Sample**

> List of maps using Google Maps API "Lite Mode" (static maps), RecyclerView/CardView, and Material Design style (AppCompat) 
>   [Example on GitHub](https://github.com/saxman/android-map_list)

[image: Google Map Light]